# Laravel 5 - Auth::attempt: Erro ao utilizar outra tabela

Tags: laravel-5, auth

Boa tarde galera, estive pesquisando na Internet e infelizmente não consegui resolver meu problema.

Preciso fazer autenticação de usuários utilizando o framework Laravel 5.2 porém meu método precisa ser diferente, ou seja, ao invés de utilizar o php artisan make:auth eu preciso fazer autenticação manual dos usuários, no caso Auth::attempt.

O meu problema é que a função está retornando FALSE. As credenciais inseridas estão corretas, porém ainda não consegui.

Configurações:

**routes.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('login', 'LoginController@login');
```

**App\User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'usuarios';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password'
    ];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($tmp)
    {
        return $this->attributes['password'] = trim(\Hash::make($tmp));
    }
}
```

**App\Controllers\LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        if (\Auth::attempt(['email' => 'admin@google.com', 'password' => '123'])) {
            return 'TRUE';
        } else {
            return 'FALSE';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Está cadastrado na tabela **users** esses dados nas colunas **email** e **password** respectivamente ?

Answer (score -1):

Vejo que não foi feito um *request* das informações, tampouco um *guard* para esses fins.

Veja o modelo abaixo e veja o que vc pode fazer .

```
 public function postlogin(loginAlunoRequest $inf_valores) {
    // atribuindo valores digitados para uma validação
    $validacao = ['RA' => $inf_valores->get('RA'), 'password' => $inf_valores->get('password'),];

    if (Auth::guard('guardLoginAluno')->attempt($validacao)) {  // Validando as informações.
        $Situacao = auth()->guard('guardLoginAluno')->user()->Situacao; // Atribuindo o valor do campo situação para uma vareavel
        if ($Situacao == "ATIVO") { // validando se o aluno esta ativo
            return redirect('/aluno'); // direcionando o usuario para pagina solicitada
        } else { // condição caso o aluno esteje inativo
            return redirect('/loginaluno') // direcionando para pagina de login 
                            ->withErrors(['Inativo' => 'Aluno Inativo!']) // messagem de erros aluno inativo
                            ->withInput(); // levando as informações de digitada de volta para o form login
        }
    } else {
        return redirect('/loginaluno') // caso a senha ou ra esteja incorretos
                        ->withErrors(['ERRO-LOGIN' => 'RA ou Senha Inválidos!']) // messagem de dados invalidos
                        ->withInput(); // levando as informações de digitada de volta para o form login
    }
```